# Reqwest request not getting my reqwest::Client's default headers

Tags: api, rest, rust, reqwest, todoist

I am trying to write a library that communicates with Todoist's REST API. The idea is that the library exposes a TodoistAPI struct that contains a reqwest::Client and a base_url. There is a `new()` function that returns the an instantiated TodoistAPI struct with a client that has a bearer token (supplied by a program utilizing my library) in its default headers.

However, I am running into an issue where when it comes time to actually use the Client to make an API request, the default headers are not getting set at all.

The `TodoistAPI` struct, `new` method, and `get_projects` method.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TodoistAPI{
    base_url: Url,
    client: reqwest::Client
}

impl TodoistAPI {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub fn new(token: &str) -> Result<TodoistAPI, TodoistAPIError> {
        let mut headers = header::HeaderMap::new();
        let header_token_value = header::HeaderValue::from_str(token).map_err(TodoistAPIError::InvalidHeaderValue)?;
        headers.insert(header::HeaderName::from_bytes(b"Bearer").map_err(TodoistAPIError::InvalidHeaderName)?, header_token_value);
        let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
            .default_headers(headers)
            .build().map_err(TodoistAPIError::Error)?;
        println!("{:#?}", client);
        let base_url = Url::parse(BASE_URL).map_err(TodoistAPIError::UrlParseError)?;
        return Ok(TodoistAPI{ base_url, client })
    }

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub async fn get_projects(&self) -> Result<Vec<Project>, TodoistAPIError> {
        let url = self.base_url.join("projects").map_err(TodoistAPIError::UrlParseError)?;
        let request_builder = self.client.request(reqwest::Method::GET, url);
        println!("{:#?}", request_builder);
        let request = request_builder.build().map_err(TodoistAPIError::Error)?;
        println!("{:#?}", request);
        let response = self.client.execute(request).await.map_err(TodoistAPIError::Error)?;
        println!("Status: {}", response.status());
        println!("STatus: {:#?}", response.text().await.map_err(TodoistAPIError::Error)?);
        let url = self.base_url.join("projects").map_err(TodoistAPIError::UrlParseError)?;
        let projects = self.client.get(url)
            .send()
            .await.map_err(TodoistAPIError::Error)?
            .json::<Vec<Project>>()
            .await.map_err(TodoistAPIError::Error)?;
        return Ok(projects);
    }
}
```

A small CLI program that gets token from environment variable and calls the `get_projects` method.

```rust
use structopt::StructOpt;
use oxidoist_api::TodoistAPI;
use oxidoist_api::Project;
use oxidoist_api::TodoistAPIError;

use std::env;

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct Cli {
    verb: String, //get, add, complete, etc.
    datatype: String, //project, task, section, etc.
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), TodoistAPIError> {
    let args = Cli::from_args();
    let token = env::var("TODOIST_API_KEY").unwrap();
    let todoist_api_object = TodoistAPI::new(token.as_str()).unwrap();
    if args.verb == "get" {
        if args.datatype == "projects" {
            let projects: Vec<Project> = todoist_api_object.get_projects().await?;
            println!("{:?}", projects);
        }
    }
    
    Ok(())
}
```

The `println!` statements result in the following output (with some obviously redacted private information).

```
Client {
    accepts: Accepts,
    proxies: [
        Proxy(
            System(
                {},
            ),
            None,
        ),
    ],
    referer: true,
    default_headers: {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "bearer": "REDACTED",
    },
}
RequestBuilder {
    method: GET,
    url: Url {
        scheme: "https",
        host: Some(
            Domain(
                "api.todoist.com",
            ),
        ),
        port: None,
        path: "/rest/v1/projects",
        query: None,
        fragment: None,
    },
    headers: {},
}
Request {
    method: GET,
    url: Url {
        scheme: "https",
        host: Some(
            Domain(
                "api.todoist.com",
            ),
        ),
        port: None,
        path: "/rest/v1/projects",
        query: None,
        fragment: None,
    },
    headers: {},
}
Status: 400 Bad Request
STatus: "Empty token\n"
Error: Error(reqwest::Error { kind: Decode, source: Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 1) })
```

I'm truly stumped here. Everything I am reading says that I am doing it right, but the default headers are definitely NOT getting added to requests spawned from the Client.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I was misunderstanding of a couple of things. First, the headers. Turns out I was just putting them in incorrectly. The header name needed to be `b"Authorization"`, and the value needed to be `"Bearer <token>"`. I have changed the code to be the following:

```rust
let mut token: String = "Bearer ".to_string();
token.push_str(&self.token);
let header_token_value = header::HeaderValue::from_str(&token).map_err(TodoistAPIError::InvalidHeaderValue)?;
```

Secondly, even after getting it to work correctly, the `headers: {}` entry in the `Request` and `RequestBuilder` printouts was still blank, so I guess reqwest merges them with the `Client`'s `default_headers` when it actually sends the request.

There may be better ways to handle the Bearer token thing, it feels a bit clumsy. If anyone finding this knows of any feel free to leave a better answer.